# React component position styling best practice

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to get an understanding on what people would consider best practice for layout of their react components, and if the layout styling should or should not be tightly coupled within the component itself.

Say I have a custom component that will be reused many times within the application, there may be times when I was them to be stacked Vertically down the page, with `margin-bottom:20px;`, whereas there may be cases I would like them spread out horizontally across the page with `margin-right:20px;`

It doesn't feel right if I were to have `margin`s, or other layout attributes tightly coupled with the component?  I would have thought that I should be able to render by component in isolation, without it having positional styling coupled along with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the component multiple times in one layout then of course the margin is not part of your component but the component that contains it.

You can use different methods to achieve your desired margin, for instance you have the css grid gap that defines just that.

However if you are using flex, you might have to pass the desired margin down to the component. So having something like this inside the component would be helpful in that case:

```
<div id="container" style={[styles.container, this.props.margin]}>
```

That way you can give it a default margin in the container style while still allowing yourself to pass a dynamic value through props when using in different places.

Comment: using lodash is a little unnecessary since style prop can have an array of objects. `style={[styles.container, this.props.margin]}`

Comment: CSS rules apply. If you have same prop multiple times in a CSS rule, later one gets applied. This lets you have default props for your component style and later if its necessary you can override them.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a prop that defines the type of the component, let's say, a **type** prop. And you can apply the classes based on the type prop you receive with a default type.

```
static propTypes = { type: PropTypes.oneOf(['info', 'warning', 'error']) };
default propTypes = { type: 'info' };
```

and the render would look like this :

```
<div className={styles[this.props.type]}>content</div>
```

Or you can just have a single way your component look and add a className prop and/or just pass your custom styles as inline styles.

```
<MyComponent style={{ marginBottom: '30px' }} className="CustomStyleInClass" type="error" />
```

You could either use one, two or all. It depends on the component and the flexibility you need.